# how to get hours and minutes using time.localtime in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have the folling line of code which returns the hour, but how do i get hours and minutes, preferable in this format 7:45.

```
print(time.localtime().tm_hour)
```

been racking my brain for hours trying to solve this but i am only new to python lol.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `strftime()` displays the local time by default:

```
time.strftime('%H:%M')
#'03:34'
```